# Nelder Mead function fit error estimation via surface fit?

Tags: optimization, confidence-interval

I'm using Nelder-Mead's simplex-downhill algorithm to fit 3 parameters (a,b,c) of a non-linear function (2d input in 1d output). 
$$
f(x,y)=\frac{a\cdot (b+x)^2}{(2+y\cdot c)^2}
$$

**Now I would like to estimate the parameter errors that the found optimum has.**

Nelder and Mead proposed in their paper from 1965 to use the final simplex, add all middle points beetween two points and do a quadratic surface fit
(Appendix of: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.144.5920&rep=rep1&type=pdf ).

This fit can then be expressed as 
$$
y=a_0+\sum_i a_ix_i + \sum_{ij} b_{ij}x_ix_j
$$
with 
$$
\begin{align}
a_0&=y_0\\
a_i&=2y_{0i}-(y_i+3y_0)/2,&&i=1,...,n\\
b_{ii}&=2(y_i+y_0-2y_{0i}),&&i=1,...,n\\
b_{ij}&=2(y_{ij}+y_0-y_{0i}-y_{0j}),&&i\neq j
\end{align}
$$

with this the variance-covariance matrix can be calculated, whose diagonal elements yield the parameter errors.

- Isn't it a chicken/egg story that I need to do a fit to estimate errors of my fit?
- Isn't the error of the surface fit important for my original fit error?
- Doing a surface fit for the 3 parameters needs a1-a3,b11-b33 = 12 new fit parameter to estimate the error of the original 3 fit parameters?

I also thought about changing each calibrant within it's error and redoing the fit. 6 calibrants would require the algorithm to run 1+2*6=13 times instead of 1, though... changing them in all combinations would be 1+6!= 721 times... Even if the simplex is faster when the last optimum is used as a new starting point, this would still drastically increase the run-time.

Should I do another simplex-downhill for the surface-fit and ignore it's errors or is there a better way to error estimate for my fitted parameters?

Answer (score 1):

After reflecting about the paper for a few hours, I think I finally understand the procedure...

## Procedure

1. you take your simplex points $p_i,i=0,1,...,N$ and make a new coordinate system with them so you get $x_i,i=0,i=0,1,...,N$ with $x_0=(0,...,0)$

   - since you have N+1 points in Dimension N you can make 3 axes with one point as the systems origin
   - the new system is scaled so that all points are 1 unit away from center ($p_1(a,b,c)\to x_1(1,0,0)$)
2. create middle-points between your simplex points.

   - They always are between two simplex points and their index indicates that (simplex 1 & 2 → middlepoint 12)
   - Their position is not important. Important is only their value (for what your simplex was optimized) and index. The value $y$ is the average value of the forming two simplex points.
3. do a quadratic surface fit.

   - $y=a_0+a'x+x'bx$
   - \begin{align}
     a_0&=y_0\\
     a_i&=2y_{0i}-(y_i+3y_0)/2,&&i=1,...,n\\
     b_{ii}&=2(y_i+y_0-2y_{0i}),&&i=1,...,n\\
     b_{ij}&=2(y_{ij}+y_0-y_{0i}-y_{0j}),&&i\neq j
     \end{align}
   - these formulas are correct in the transformed coordinate system. In here, B is the information matrix. This means, $a_0$ and $a$ are not important and can be neglected. This also means only the quadratic terms influence the parameter error.
4. now we transform B into our coordinate system:

   - $Q=\left(\begin{matrix}\uparrow&\uparrow&\\p_1-p_0&p_2-p_0&\cdots\\\downarrow&\downarrow\end{matrix}\right)$ of the original points
   - ${Q^{-1}}'HQ^{-1}$ is the information matrix in the original coordinate system, so $C=QH^{-1}Q'$ is the covariance-matrix.
5. squareroot of the diagonal entries of C is the parameter error.

## Example

As a simple example of application we have a 2D-System with final simplex points

- $p_0=(1,2),~p_1=(2,3),~p_2=(3,1)$ and $y_0=2,~y_1=1,~y_2=3$.
- Now we imagine our new coordinate system with our middle point values of $y_{01}=1.5,~y_{02}=2.5,~y_{12}=2$.
- calculate b: $b_{11}=2(1+2-2*1.5)=0,~b_{22}=2(3+2-2*2.5)=0,~b_{12}=2(1.5+2-1-2)=1$
- $\Rightarrow B=\left(\begin{matrix}0&1\\1&0\end{matrix}\right)$
- Transform into original system: $Q=\left(\begin{matrix}1&2\\1&-1\end{matrix}\right)$
- B^{-1} via pseudo-inverse $B = U\Sigma V^{H},~~\Rightarrow B^{-1}=\left(\begin{matrix}0&1\\1&0\end{matrix}\right)$
- $C=QB^{-1}Q'=\left(\begin{matrix}1&2\\1&-1\end{matrix}\right)\cdot\left(\begin{matrix}0&1\\1&0\end{matrix}\right)\cdot\left(\begin{matrix}1&1\\2&-1\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}1&2\\1&-1\end{matrix}\right)\cdot\left(\begin{matrix}2&-1\\1&1\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}4&1\\1&-2\end{matrix}\right)$

So the the best point of the simplex (downhill) was $p_1$ with $y_1=1$ at position $(2\pm2 ,3\pm\sqrt2)$

In reality the qualtiy values should be much closer together. The diagonal-elements of H seem to be 0 by default. In the end this procedure seem to assume, that a stronger curve in the quadratic fit (higher values in B) would result in a smaller confidence interval .

I hope I finally understood all the parts necessary to do an error estimation for my simplex fits. ^^